# Use same controller for two different modules in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I display the searched content details in first module. I need to display description of particular record. I have used ng-click in Image.Here my code. Please give some solutions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body>
<div class="container">
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainController">
<input type="text" ng-model="test.count">
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names | filter:test">
  <td><a href="#" ng-click="displayDescription(x)"><img src="images/{{ x.image}}.png" /></a><span>{{ x.name }}</span></td>
  <td>{{ x.brand }}</td>
  <td>{{ x.count }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="sub" ng-app="subApp" ng-controller="mainController">
<div>{{dummyContent}}
<p ng-repeat="x in names">{{ x.desc }}</p>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<script>
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp',[]);
mainApp.controller('mainController',function($scope) {
    $scope.names=[
{image:'German',name:'Sebastin Vettel',brand:'Red Bull',count:'397',desc:'Red Bull is an energy drink'},
{image:'India',name:'Shanmuga Sundaram',brand:'Kingfisher',count:'242',desc:'Kingfisher is favourite brand in India'},
{image:'Brazilian',name:'Mark Webber',brand:'Kingcobra',count:'199',desc:'Kingcobra is very worst brand i ever drink'},
{image:'Spanish',name:'Lewis Hamilton',brand:'Budweiser',count:'189', desc:'Budweiser is Best brand i ever drink'},
{image:'German',name:'Kimi Raikonnan',brand:'Fosters',count:'183', desc:'Fosters is next to  brand Budweiser'}
];
});

var subApp = angular.module('subApp',['mainApp']);
subApp.controller('mainController',function($scope) {
$scope.dummyContent = "dummt text";
  $scope.displayDescription = function(x) {
    $scope.Description = x.desc;
  };
});
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("sub"),['subApp']);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have assigned a new variable dummyContent in this second module. I can access this. But i need to access description {{x.desc}} from first module.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to share common code through services. Just create a service using one of the Angular provider models and inject it wherever it's needed.

Comment: Hi TGH, As I am new to AngularJS, I don't know how to do it in services. Is it possible or not using same controllers ??

Comment: @Shanmugam, look at the service documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services and think of how it would apply to your application structure.  You can use the same code in both controllers, but it is bad practice and not recommended.